# how to Read file and avoid 'EOF'?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to this javascript, so asking a simple question.
I am using Node.js to read a file of the following format.

```
 NAME : noname
 TYPE : filetype
 lines : 15000
 1 24 12
 2 12 33
 3 63 00
 4 .. ..
 ..............
 150000 16 91
 EOF
 'an empty line here'
```

My code is

```
var fs = require('fs');
if (fs.existsSync(filepath)) 
{
    var data_array = fs.readFileSync(filepath).toString().split("\n");

    //to check if it is reading correctly
    console.log(data_array[0]);
    console.log(data_array[1]);
    console.log(data_array[2]);
    console.log(data_array.length.toString());

}
```

but I realized that it is also reading 'EOF' line and the empty line after that.
I want it to stop when reached 'EOF'.

How to do that?

Comment: You could simply remove the last to elements in the array. But I wouldn't go for it, because when you read 200 files maybe there are 40 files that don't have that last empty line. Keep it simple and not too strict. Just ignore empty lines.

Comment: @DanFromGermany it also reading the 'EOF'. Yes, removing 2 last lines from the array is simplest, but I am wondering if there is a simple solution to avoid these last 2 lines.

Comment: The best way is to build your script to only use the  information it can work with and ignore the rest.

Comment: @DanFromGermany just used slice method to return the part I need. Ugly but works for me now.

Comment: Usually you don't read a whole file, you read it as a stream (line by line or byte by byte). Then there is no need for slicing, just use the information, or don't if it's not useful, then continue.

Answer (score 0):

If the "EOF" is something important to your business logic, and need to ignore "anything" after that, you would need custom code to achieve that. However, the file (and the file reader code in node) will automatically detect the EOF marker which is available in the file, without you adding one explicitly. If that would suffice, you may actually take out everything including EOF, and just follow the standard procedure.

It may look trivial and simple, but answering in this way based on your own caveat about your experience level in Javascript.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think he has a string "EOF" not the real EOF symbol one might expect. Because if it was real a real EOF, there would be no blank line after that.